# Context-free or not: $a^nww^Ra^n$

Tags: context-free

Is the following a context-free language?
$$L = \{a^n w w^R a^n \mid n \geq 0, w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$$

I think no because the number of $w$'s is not equal.

Somebody please guide me.

Comment: Looks context-free to me. Try constructing a grammar.

Comment: $w^R$ is reversed string $w$.

Comment: Yes it's context free. Consider  $S \rightarrow aSa | A$, and $A \rightarrow aAa | bAb | \epsilon$

Comment: Actually, the $a^n$ parts are irrelevant. This is exactly the same language as $\{ww^R \mid w\in\{a,b\}^*\}$, because $w$ itself may start with any  number of $a$'s.

Comment: Thanks all. @Dmitri you understood my weak-point. So first we would push a^n and then w in npda then at mid-point we would pop w and a^n. So they would cancel out. But how will we know that we have reached the mid-point?